# Submit application on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have finished my facebook app, but I can't submit it. I have 5 active users, so that's not a problem. I click on submit and nothing happens, apart from the url change (but the browsers is not being redirected) into this: http://www.facebook.com/developers/submitapp.php?app_id={{my application id}}. I don't get any error messages, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a current server error from facebook.

There is a bug topic about it on facebook bugzilla.

--> http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17738

But they seem not paying attention much. It's been more than 2 weeks and still no update about the error. Everyone is waiting for it to be fixed.